# Symfony3: Doctrine Transaction and EventSubscriber

Tags: symfony, doctrine, event-listener

I'm writing a method in my Symfony 3 application for bulk user creation. The flux is uploading a csv file with all the necessary data.

I created a Service, into I write all the logic of this operation. This is my Service:

```
class BulkRegistration
{
    private $em;
    private $validator;
    private $session;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, ValidatorInterface $validator, SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->validator = $validator;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function run(BulkRegistrationData $bulkRegistrationData){
        //todo rimuovere dipendenza nascosta
        $serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()], [new CsvEncoder()]);

        $datas = $serializer->decode(file_get_contents($bulkRegistrationData->csv), 'csv');

        $this->em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

        try{
            foreach($datas as $data)
            {
                $userData = UserData::create($data);
                $this->validate($userData, 'newUser');

                $userCreate = User::create($userData->user);
                $this->em->persist($userCreate);


                $this->em->flush();
            }

            $this->em->getConnection()->commit();

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->em->getConnection()->rollback();
            $this->em->close();

            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('error', $e->getMessage());

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private function validate ($entity, $validationGroup = null){
        if($validationGroup){
            $errors = $this->validator->validate($entity, null, [$validationGroup]);
        }else{
            $errors = $this->validator->validate($entity);
        }

        if (count($errors) > 0) {
            $errorMessage = '';
            foreach($errors as $error)
            {
                $errorMessage .= $error->getMessage();
            }
            throw new \Exception($errorMessage);
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Also I wrote this EmailSubscriber, for sending an activation email each time the entity User is persisted:

```
class EmailSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    private $activationEmail;

    public function __construct(SendActivationEmail $activationEmail)
    {
        $this->activationEmail = $activationEmail;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            Events::postPersist,
        );
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();

        if ($entity instanceof User)
        {
            $this->activationEmail->send($entity);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is question:

The EventSubscriber catch the persisted event before the transaction commit. 
I want or persist all the row in my db, or response with violation and ask to User to modify his csv file.

Because this, one of the useCase can be some activation email sended but no persisting the User in DB, for example for some validate violation of one of the csv row.

I hope I was crearl, the case is a bit intricate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to adjust the foreach to only flush if there were no errors:

```
foreach($datas as $data) {
    $userData = UserData::create($data);
    try {
        $this->validate($userData, 'newUser');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->em->getConnection()->rollback();
        $this->em->close();

        $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('error', $validation);

        return false;
    }
    $userCreate = User::create($userData->user);
    $this->em->persist($userCreate);
}
$this->em->flush();
$this->em->getConnection()->commit();

return true;
```

Comment: But if I don't flush anytime, some validation of userData (for example uniqueEmail) can't be intercept, so I have a sql exception and not a form violation.

Comment: Then you need to check the unique fields separately, maybe with array_count_values().

Comment: Yes, this can be a solution. But i decided to change my way, to do something less intricate. I popolate and userArray and send email manually. 
Thanks for the help.